# Strange artefacts in PDF output with cm-super package

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf, font-encodings, viewers

The following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}
\textbf{U}
\end{document}
```

Compiled **without** the `cm-super` package, produces a PDF, which in Adobe Acrobate Reader, Zoom Level 125%, looks like this:

[image]

This is fine. The same code compiled **with** the `cm-super` package, produces a PDF, which in Adobe Acrobate Reader, Zoom Level 125%, looks like this:

[image]

This looks much worse than before. Where do these strange artifacts at the top of the U come from? And how can I fix this?

I don't want compile without this package because it is seemingly the only way to have searchable umlauts (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604256/searchable-umlauts-without-any-font-change) question).

Here is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7380 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.4.6)  11 JUL 2021 12:20
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
("C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
) ("C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.st
y"
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backe
nd-pdfmode.def"
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count175
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
) (test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
 [1

{C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (test.aux
) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 572 strings out of 480897
 7854 string characters out of 2897717
 239429 words of memory out of 12000000
 16536 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 534190 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,21p,148b,97s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/
cm-super-t1.enc}<C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/
public/cm-super/sfbx1095.pfb><C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9
/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1095.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 16297 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Exactly which latex installation are you using (I'm assuming miktex). Can you also share the complete log of your compilation of the mwe

Comment: @daleif I added the log file.

Comment: Your miktex is not fully up to date

Comment: @daleif Is this the root cause of the problem?

Comment: You'll have to ask Ulrike about it, I only use texlive which have used cm-super as the default the last at least 15 years. Are you sure this is not screen rendering artifacts? That is do they go away if you zoom in more?

Comment: @daleif it is a  rendering artifact, I can see it at some zooms.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer then I assume there isn't much we can do

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think I found a solution, using \RequirePackage{fix-cm} before documentclass seems to fix the problem. It also fixes the problem from my previous question that the captions look different (they look good now). There is however a new problem, because now the bold L now has some artefacts. I also noticed that cm-super (with or without fix-cm) causes rendering problem of height of letters like in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98410/why-does-latin-modern-make-strange-appearing-output) old question (which is in my optinion wrongfully marked as a duplicate).